# Link button CSS increases the font size when mousehover

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio

I have a asp.net link button and i have applied below css on it

```
.linkbutton
{

    font-size:10px; 
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif; 
    font-style:normal;  
}
```

When i mouse-hover the link button, the font-size grows!. Why it happens that way?

Comment: I guess there's a :hover rule somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there it is. I believe its because of this that the hover is happening

Comment: @Xor, umm, haven't you just answered your own question then? What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a rule for the hover or a href (whichever is being generated) that sets a bold or an font size value that is different.

You could try adding a rule like this:

```
.linkbutton:hover
{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

It would be better if you could post some sample code as the answer is going to be an issue specific to your page / css files rather than a general piece of advice.

Answer (score 0):

Run the app in your browser and start developertools (in Chrome press shift-ctrl-i, or download 'Firebug' for Firefox).

Then select the button and you can see which classes are inherited by that button and then you can fix the :hover problem.